# Django Listview - Filter and Pagination

Tags: python, django, listview, pagination

I'm new to django. I'm trying to create two table, first one with the lastest added products filter by publication_date and second one with the upcoming products filter  by release_date.
Here my `homepage.html` code :

```
...
{% for prodotto in products %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ prodotto.title }}</td>
  <td>{{ prodotto.description }}</td>
  <td>{{ prodotto.publication_date|date:"d/m/Y" }}</td>
  <td>{{ prodotto.release_date|date:"d/m/Y" }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}

...

...
{% for prodotto in products %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ prodotto.title }}</td>
  <td>{{ prodotto.description }}</td>
  <td>{{ prodotto.publication_date|date:"d/m/Y" }}</td>
  <td>{{ prodotto.release_date|date:"d/m/Y" }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

here my `model.py` :

```
class Products(models.Model):
...
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publication_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    release_date = models.DateTimeField()
...
```

here my `view.py` :

```
class home(ListView):
    queryset = Products.objects.all()
    template_name = 'homepage.html'
    context_object_name = "products"
```

Currently i'm able to only show all the products without filtering.
I'm trying to also add pagination only in the first table,but I don't have an idea how to filter and add pagination in my `homepage.html`.

I've tried adding pagination by adding `paginate_by = 5` into `view.py` but with this method,it's adding pagination in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly in your template:

```
{% for prodotto in products|slice:":5" %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ prodotto.title }}</td>
  <td>{{ prodotto.description }}</td>
  <td>{{ prodotto.publication_date|date:"d/m/Y" }}</td>
  <td>{{ prodotto.release_date|date:"d/m/Y" }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Nice! But with the slice filter, how i can add pagination?